# Finding the intersection between several sets in a list

Tags: python, string, set, intersection

I have a list containing several sets {} with different names and string values.

eg.

```
set1 = {"a", "santa", "clock"}
search = {"why", "is", "santa", "nice"}

list_of_sets = [set1, search]
```

I want to find the intersection between the sets in the list through a function:

```
def intersection_between_sets_from_list(list_of_sets):
    """ find the intersection between the sets here"""
    return intersection_strings
```

any idea what code to use in """ find the intersection between the sets here""".

Answer (score 1):

If you want find the intersection between all sets in the list you could be iterate on `list_of_set` and find the intersection between the current set and your temporal set like this:

```
tmp = list_of_sets[0]
for e in list_of_sets:
    tmp = tmp.intersection(e)
```

but this operation on python language could be do:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x.intersection(y), list_of_sets)
```